# Why intersection observer does not work on all the Browser? And is it good to use polyfill instead if intersection observer not available

Tags: polyfills, intersection-observer

Why intersection observer does not work on all the Browser?

And is it good to use polyfill instead, if intersection observer not available?

I wanted to know if polyfill is also optimized as Intersection Observer. If polyfill creating any impact on performance then I will avoid using it